# What kind of state is the ACTION_APPWIDGET_RESTORED broadcast about?

Tags: android, android-appwidget, appwidgetprovider

I'm searching for the best way to back up the current state of my app widget. I've got a bitmap and I remember its timestamp:

```
private data class TimestampedBitmap(val bitmap : Bitmap, val timestamp : Long)

private var tsBitmap: TimestampedBitmap? = null
```

However, if my app gets killed-restarted, i lose my `tsBitmap` instance. I want to avoid having to reload this data from the network (there may be no network connection to begin with) and I'm looking for the most elegant approach to achieve it.

I studied the documentation for `AppWidgetProvider.onUpdate()`:

> Called in response to the `AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE` and `AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_RESTORED` broadcasts when this `AppWidget` provider is being asked to provide `RemoteViews` for a set of `AppWidget`s.

The second event type sounds interesting. This is what the official docs have to say:

> `String ACTION_APPWIDGET_RESTORED`
>
> Sent to an `AppWidgetProvider` after `AppWidget` state related to that provider has been restored from backup. The intent contains information about how to translate `AppWidget` ids from the restored data to their new equivalents.

What, technically speaking, is the "state related to that provider"? Can I make `TimestampedBitmap` become a part of that state? I realize that this event type is about restoring from a backup only at the time the app is (re)installed, but I still wonder whether the kind of state it talks about is the one that I should be using?